# What's wrong with my permutation logic?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

The given question:

> In how many ways the letters of the word RAINBOW be arranged, such that A is always before I and I is always before O.

I gave it a try and thought below:

> Letters A, I and O should appear in that order. Then there are four places in which all the remaining four letters can appear. It means there are a total of 16 places: $$*_1*_2*_3*_4\quad A\quad*_5*_6*_7*_8\quad I\quad*_9*_{10}*_{11}*_{12}\quad O \quad *_{13}*_{14}*_{15}*_{16}$$ 
>   Out of these 16 places remaining, the letter can appear in any of the 4 places, giving total $^{16}P_4 = 43680$ possible arrangements.

But the given answer is just 840 with following explanation:

> All the 7 letters of the word RAINBOW can be arranged in 7! ways and 3 particular letters (A,I,O) can be arranged in 3! ways. But the given condition is satisfied by only 1 out of 6 ways. Hence required number of arrangements 
>   $$=\frac{7!}{3!} = 840$$

So what's wrong with my logic? I must be counting certain arrangements multiple times or my logic must be at fault in large. But what's that exactly?

Comment: Not an answer, but a sanity check: You could know that you were overcounting without knowing the exact answer, since there cannot be more of these arrangements than total arrangements (with no restrictions), and there are only $7!=5040$ of those.

Comment: yep I got that sensation already

Comment: You're counting "R in 1, N in 2, B in 3, W in 5" and "R in 1, N in 2, B in 3, W in 6" even though both of those make RNBAWIO

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the arrangement RAINBOW you have counted four places the R can be, four places the W can be, and six ways of putting NB in that order between the I and O, so you have counted it $96$ times. Other arrangements have been counted multiple times as well.

Answer (score 8):

Ross Millikan has already explained the error in your reasoning. Here’s a correct version of the kind of calculation that you were trying to make. There are $\binom73$ ways to choose $3$ positions for the letters A, I, and O. The remaining $4$ letters can fill the remaining $4$ slots in any order, so they can be inserted in $4!$ ways. That gives you a total of

$$4!\binom73=\frac{7!}{3!}=840$$

arrangements.

Answer (score 5):

Your mistake is here:

> Out of these 16 places remaining letter can appear in any 4 places,
>   giving total $^{16}P_4=43680$ possible arrangements.

The 43680 placements of letters into four of the 16 positions don’t yield different arrangements of the letters. For example, one arrangement is RAINBOW. Is the letter R in position 1, 2, 3, or 4? You counted each of those placements separately.

Answer (score 4):

You would be entirely correct if there really were 16 places ( 19 in all ) and the places not filled with letters were filled with spaces so that

```
R***A****I*N*BO**W*
```

was truly distinct from

`*R**A****I*N*BO***W`    ( I has used * because spaces are hard to count )

what $ ^{16} P _4$ counts is the number of four-tuples with non-repeating elements from 1 to 16. 
You might have the first element represent the position ( in your scheme of 16 positions ) of the letter "R" and the other three the positions of "N", "B", and "W" respectively.

so that  `R***A****I*N*BO**W*` would be represented as (1, 10, 12, 15)

and `*R**A****I*N*BO***W` would be represented as (2, 10, 12, 16) .

Answer (score 1):

I think the closest method to your original attempt is the following: after laying out the fixed letters A, I and O, consider one additional letter at a time.

(1) We have: " A I O ". R can be placed in any of four places.

(2) We now have four placed letters, for example " R A I O ". In any case we have five locations in which the next letter N can be placed.

(3) Similarly when we place the B, there are 6 choices of where to put it among the existing 5 letters.

(4) And finally the last letter W can be placed among the 6 existing letters in any of 7 places.

Each combination of choices will lead to a different outcome, as any two outcomes must differ by the order of as at least one pair of letters.

So the total number of orders is: 4 * 5 * 6 * 7 = 840

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer above, but when I tried to solve the same problem I applied slightly different thinking to same solution.  Thus sharing it here.

The book says:

> All the 7 letters of the word RAINBOW can be arranged in 7! ways and 3 particular letters (A,I,O) can be arranged in 3! ways. But the given condition is satisfied by only 1 out of 6 ways. Hence required number of arrangements 
>   $$=\frac{7!}{3!} = 840$$

We can also think it as follows:

> There are 7 letters in $RAINBOW$. Out which 3 are A, I and O, ***in that order*** (i.e. they cannot be in any other order I, A and O). So they can be at any of $\binom{7}{3}$ positions. Now remaining 4 letters are $R,N,B$ and $W$, in ***any order***, so they take $4P_4$ positions. The total is
>   $$\binom{7}{3}\times4P_4=\frac{7!}{4!\times3!}\times4!=\frac{7!}{3!}$$

Just a little bit of different thinking.